# Reload content inside a UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I'm trying to change the content & reload the UIPickerView when the user clicks on a button.

When the button gets pressed I call `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]`

The content changes on scrolling when new rows are drawn but the number of rows keeps the same i.e. `- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;`
 doesn't get called.

Does `[pickerView reloadAllComponents]` work as I imagine, changes the dataSource & redraws the content from the UIPickerView?

If not, how should I do that?

Comment: are you sure you hooked up `pickerView`? sounds like you `reloadAllComponents` call doesn't reach the `UIPickerView`. On scrolling you would always expect new content, even without the reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake.

I was creating the same UIPickerView in viewDidLoad in code too:
`productsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];`

Dumb mistake, but very hard to notice.